# Duplicating markers problem with setInterval on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I wrote

```
function callAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/device_new',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var markerGroup = L.featureGroup();
                var coordinates = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {
                         marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
                            .bindPopup("Device: " + coordinates[i].device_type + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime)
                            .addTo(map);

                            marker.addTo(markerGroup);                           
                    }
                }
            map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());
            },

            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
        setInterval(callAjax,30000);

    }
```

And every 30 second when my map refreshes, but every time it duplicate markers, shadow become darker, and it spent much resources on PC.

Can it be prevented?

Comment: can you share what are you performing in function?

Comment: pls share more code. what does your function `myFunction`? Also try to add the maker to a featuregroup `var fg = L.featureGroup(); fg.addTo(map); [.....] marker.addto(fg); ` also before you add the markers call `fg.clearLayers()` to reset the old markers

Comment: I edited post, so you can se full code.

Comment: I tried it, but looks like .clearLayer() dont work in my function

Answer (score 0):

Put all markers into a layerGroup or a featureGroup:

```
var markerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
```

add the markers to the group:

```
L.marker([lon, lat]).addTo(markerGroup);
```

Then use the **clearLayers()** method on that group to remove all markers.

```
markerGroup.clearLayers();
```

Comment: method markerGroup.clearLayers(); delete all layers in my map